# Why do we have to use an article in this sentence before gerund?

Tags: articles

Why in the second sentence we must use article:

> 1. I am angry abut making environment dirty by some people.
> 2. I am angry about **the** governing my country by the king.

Comment: It should be "the governing **of** my country" ... and your first sentence is full of errors.

Answer (score 3):

Sentence one needs a complete rewrite. An English speaker would never express it in this way.

> 2. I am angry about the governing **of** my country by the king.

This sentence states that the speaker is angry about **the** way that the king governs the country. Note that it is **the** way... It refers to a particular way, and so a definite article is required. For the same reason, a definite article is required when the speaker says  "**the** governing".

Note that, while it is possible to use a gerund in this sentence, there are two simple nouns ([governance](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/governance) and [government](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/government)) which can be used to describe the process related to the verb govern. When such a noun exists, many english speakers prefer to the simple noun rather than a gerund.

> I am angry about the governance of my country by the king

Answer (score 0):

"I am angry about the governing of my country by the king." Is correct. 'I' is the subject, "governing of my country" is the direct object, so 'the' is necessary. Also, the first sentence is incorrect, "I am angry abut making environment dirty by some people." Should be, "I am angry about some people making the environment dirty," or "I am angry about the dirtying of the environment by some people."

Comment: I have seen  gerund after prepisition without article but in this centence article was used . What is difference between these centences

Comment: @Hamid Give me specific examples of sentences. For better understanding you can fry 'sentence diagramming' http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/diagrams2/one_pager1.htm   http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/verbals.html

Comment: @Emily88034 I fried that link, but it stuck to my skillet.

Comment: @P.E.Dant then you didn't use enough oil